# Why is this regex expression not working?

Tags: python, regex

I want to separate out the links from the string which don't have ':' in between and do not end with '.jpg' or '.svg', and also start with '/wiki/'.

So these are wrong -

```
"https://boomerrang.com"
"/wiki/sbsbs:kjanw"
"/wiki/aswaa:asawsa.jpg"
"/wiki/awssa.random.jpg"
"/wiki/boom.jpg"
```

How the final result should look like -

```
"/wiki/justthis"
```

**What I tried -**

```
r'^/wiki/.*[^:](?!jpg|svg)$'
```

But its not evaluating properly, infact its giving all the result which I do not want... I'm kind of new to regex, so please tell me why this is not working, and how should I correct it.

Thanks

Comment: how should look the ending result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your pattern doesn't work:

`.*[^:]` doesn't prevent a `:` to be present in the string since `.*` can match it.

`(?!jpg|svg)$` doesn't make sense since it says that the end of the string isn't followed by "jpg" or "svg". Obviously the end of the string isn't followed by anything since it's the end of the string. Keep in mind that a lookaround (lookahead or lookbehind), anchors like `^`, `$` or a word-boundary `\b` are *zero-width assertions* and don't consume characters, so `(?!jpg|svg)` and `$` are tested from the same position in the string.

You can try that:

```
r'^/wiki/[^:]*(?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.svg)$'
```

The two negative lookbehinds at the end ensure that the string doesn't end with `.svg` or `.jpg`.

`[^:]*` avoids any `:` in the string.

Comment: Wow, this worked like a charm, can you please explain this in short? And do really not need to escape forward slash as opposed to the suggestion in the comments?

Comment: @numpy: did you refresh the current page? About what in particular do you need more informations?

Comment: @numpy I suggest you paste that regex here: http://regex101.com and you will get a breakdown of what each thing does, and you can play around with it more to have a further understanding.

Comment: (?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.svg)$ just the explanation about this grouping... '?<' sequence

Comment: @numpy: `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind, it means *not preceded by*. As the lookahead, a lookbehind is only a test that doesn't consume character (it's a zero-width assertion). Note that in the current pattern you can put `(?<!\.jpg)`, `(?<!\.svg)` and `$` in the order you want, it doesn't change anything.